# How will maximo identity which user to log out of admin mode?

Tags: maximo

If 10 user are logged in at a time and I change my database adjusting a setting to the following:

> Number of Administrative Sessions Allowed:5"

how will maximo identify which 5 user remain logged in.

Answer (score 2):

If any of the Maxadmin users are logged in, they will not be logged out. If in case, there are 10 users who all are MAXADMINs and only 5 are authorized users in Admin Mode, the people who are Inactive for longer time will be logged out.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the MAXADMIN security role. Any users on the application that is not part of MAXADMIN will be kicked out and not allowed to login until you take the Maximo application out of Admin Mode. Admin Mode allows you to perform many application configuration and database configuration without having to stop MXServer (maximo.ear).

Comment: can u plz.. explain... what you trin to say.

Comment: What is it that you are confused about?

Comment: is there any option in maximo by which we identify .. which particular administrative session allowed ? during admin mode turn on...

Comment: If the user has maxadmin security role, they can be logged in. Check maxsession table if you want to see who is logged. If you have more than one maxadmin, you have to coordinate between yourselves. There shouldn't be more than one person migrating code, updating the ui, or updating the database anyway.

Comment: one more question suppose i created a relationship between ownergroup and persongroup   "ownergroup=:persongroup'" what its actual mean

Answer (score 0):

Some systems may have customized MAXADMIN security groups, and the MAXADMIN user will be a part of all these 'custom' groups. In this case, only those users who are atleast present in the groups same as MAXADMIN user, will not be logged out of Maximo during Admin mode.
for eg. MAXADMIN user is present in these security groups: MAXADMIN, MAXADMIN_CUST1, MAXADMIN_CUST2. 
Now, if user USER1 does not want to be kicked off during admin mode, he will have to be in atleast these groups: MAXADMIN, MAXADMIN_CUST1, MAXADMIN_CUST2.